# Trying to upload an screenshot from Unity to web server

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, post, xampp

I am currently trying to upload a screenshot taken from Unity and Post it to my web server, storing it in a folder. (I am using *XAMPP* for testing this)

I can take the screenshot without any problems, but I think I'm doing something wrong when trying to send it as a Post in my script.

I've tried to make a basic *html* form and test it and in this way I can store it successfully, but when trying from my Unity project. Nothing happens.

I have a folder named "***upload***" and it is located in the same folder as the *php* script.

I have searched for an answer, but had not found anything that has been working so far. And since every other similar question is about the Legacy *WWW* function in Unity. I've decided to try and make a new thread.

Hope this makes some kind of sense, and any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code from ***Unity***:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.IO;


public class ScreenShotScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool grab = false;
    byte[] bytes;

    private void Update()
    {
        //Press space to start the screen grab
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            grab = true;
            TakePicture();
        }
    }

    //Function to take a screenshot.
    public void TakePicture()
    {
        if (grab)
        {
            int width = Screen.width;
            int height = Screen.height;

            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
            tex.Apply();

            bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
            Destroy(tex);

            //Testing to see if I can store the image local
            File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/screenShot.png", bytes);
            Debug.Log("Saved the Image!");

            StartCoroutine(SendImage());
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator SendImage()
    {
        List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();

        formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("file", bytes));

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/postimage-test.php", formData);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

***Php Script:***

```
<!--For testing purpose, to see if I can upload an image by a html form. -->
<html>
    <body>

    <form action="postimage-test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
<?php

  if ($_POST) {

    $target_dir = "upload/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    //Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    }
    //Else everything is ok, try to upload file
    else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    // }

  }
  else {
    echo "No Post! ";
  }
?>
```

Comment: [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) will show you whether Unity is actually making a request to your PHP code, as well as what the PHP is responding with.

Comment: As far as I can see in Fiddler. It does make a request to my PHP code , and I can even see my encoded .png being sent as the file. But never get a response from the PHP code.

Comment: So this seems to be more related to PHP and barely to Unity and C#

Comment: Do you get any error output? On the php side you could try to actively set the [http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/de/function.http-response-code.php)